# Haproxy ACL rule for a particular domain

Tags: linux, configuration, haproxy, access-control-list

In my Haproxy config I have few ACL rule set. My haproxy.config looks like,

```
frontend incoming
bind *:80

  acl grow_mydomain hdr(host) grow.mydoamin.com
    use_backend grow_mydomain if grow_mydomain

  acl staging_mydomain hdr(host) staging.mydomain.com
    use_backend staging_mydomain if staging_mydomain
```

Now, I want set another rule to block bad bots. New ACL rule, I want to add,

```
  acl blockedagent hdr_reg(user-agent) -i -f /etc/haproxy/badbots.lst
    http-request deny if blockedagent
```

Now, I want to apply the `badbots` ACL rule only for the domain `grow.mydomain.com` . It should not consider the domain `staging.mydomain.com`

I tried the below approach, but it is not working. Because, it is considering both the domains.

```
frontend incoming
bind *:80

  acl blockedagent hdr_reg(user-agent) -i -f /etc/haproxy/badbots.lst
    http-request deny if blockedagent

  acl grow_mydomain hdr(host) grow.mydoamin.com
    use_backend grow_mydomain if grow_mydomain

  acl staging_mydomain hdr(host) staging.mydomain.com
    use_backend staging_mydomain if staging_mydomain
```

What is the recommended way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list multiple ACLs in the `if` condition

`http-request deny if blockedagent grow_mydomain`